# Need to replace NA in age with fixed mean 25 and st 2

Tags: r, random

I did this,

```
data$Age <- sapply(data$Age, function(x) 
             replace(x, is.na(x), rnorm(sum(is.na(x)), mean=mean, sd=std))))
```

however, it has some negative values. for age it is an error, how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Now I did a loop, but it does not replace the negative age value. What I did wrong? `positiv_rnum <- function(x, mean, std){
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    while (x[i] <= 0) {
      message("negative value ", x[i])
      x[i] <- rnorm(1, mean=mean, sd=std)
      data$Age[i] <- rnorm(1, mean=mean, sd=std)
      message("replaced value ", data$age[i])
    }
     
  }
}
positiv_rnum(data$Age, mean, std)`

Comment: Is there any sort of trend in which values are negative. I just ran your `rnorm` 5000 times `x<-rnorm(5000, mean=25, sd=2)` and did not get any negative values. Am I misinterpreting what you are trying to do? Are the mean and SD not constant?

Comment: Lol @Tanner33 just for giggles I ran `x <- rnorm(1000000000, 25, 2)` and `min(x)
[1] 12.54097`

Comment: @Chck P Haha, I think it is a pretty safe bet that no negative numbers will results form that mean and SD.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution.  With a mean of 25 and sd of 2 you should essentially never get a negative age.

I made a column of all `NA` just for fun.

```r
set.seed(2020)
data <- data.frame(Age = sample(0:100, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                   many = NA_integer_)
head(data)
#>   Age many
#> 1  27   NA
#> 2  86   NA
#> 3  21   NA
#> 4  87   NA
#> 5  64   NA
#> 6  16   NA

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(many = replace_na(many, 
                            rnorm(n = 1, 
                                  mean = 25, 
                                  sd = 2)))
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      Age  many
#>    <int> <dbl>
#>  1    27  27.2
#>  2    86  24.6
#>  3    21  23.9
#>  4    87  25.8
#>  5    64  24.3
#>  6    16  27.6
#>  7    35  30.0
#>  8    41  26.6
#>  9    69  25.0
#> 10    48  21.9
#> # … with 990 more rows
```

This simpler `sapply` also works

```r
data$many <- sapply(data$many, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), rnorm(1, mean = 25, sd = 2)))
```

Comment: Thanks Chuck, two points: 1. rnorm(1, mean = 25, sd = 2) has no mean since you only asking return one value, so mean and sd are meaningless. 2. I was just wandering (x, mean, sd) never has a case that people want to specify a rang?  in the example, if sd goes to a smaller value it does return negative values (very few). Thanks for reply. it does help a lot.

Comment: Hi Gary, you're wrong about several things.  If `sd` gets smaller as you say then negative numbers are even **less** likely.  Running `rnorm` n independent times does produce independent values as you can clearly see from the `many` column in the example I gave you.  The mean and sd of that column are approximately 25 and 2 respectively just as if you asked for a sample of size n by running it once. Is your question really that you want a random distribution from a truncated normal distribution.  There is no such base function but it's possible to write a custom function to do so.